# Django upload form issue, no image selected

Tags: django, image, upload

i'm trying to solve a little issue with my upload file problem in my django 1.5 application. I downloaded a sort of example, but i have some problem with that.
When i press the ulpoad button it says to me that it's empty, but that it's not true...

this is my  upload form:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(
    label='Select a file'
```

this is the view

```
def image(request, auction_event_id):
# Handle file upload
try:
    auction_event = AuctionEvent.objects.get(pk=auction_event_id)
except AuctionEvent.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.save()

        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('com:auction_view_auction_event', args=(auction_event.pk,)))
else:
    form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()

# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render_to_response(
    'auction/setimages.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

and the model

```
class Document(models.Model):
auction_event = models.ForeignKey(AuctionEvent, related_name='images')
docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual reason for this is that you've forgotten to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the HTML form tag. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form).